# How to send callback data using Telegram API sendGame method

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send Game using Telegram bot API sendGame method, but I also need an ID that will be passing to my game URL
like : `https://mygame.com?id=123`

I try to use the callback data,
`https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/sendGame?chat_id=[chat id]&game_short_name=luckySpin&reply_markup={"text":"Spin","callback_game":[[{"callback_data":"id-123"}]]}`
the JSON response was :

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":316,"from":{"id":1657959350,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"fred Admin Bot","username":"fredAdminBot"},"chat":{"id":[chat id],"first_name":"Fredy Kardian","last_name":"Udo","username":"fredykardian","type":"private"},"date":1612566258,"game":{"title":"Lucky Spin","description":"Lucky Spin","photo":[{"file_id":"AgACAgUAAxUAAWAdzvLbYgEGIlW5Ox2vkzdrY_vfAAIgqzEbeTbJVM_WmQrJtBEAAaCD7G50AAMBAAMCAANtAAMI3QEAAR4E","file_unique_id":"AQADoIPsbnQAAwjdAQAB","file_size":10256,"width":320,"height":180},{"file_id":"AgACAgUAAxUAAWAdzvLbYgEGIlW5Ox2vkzdrY_vfAAIgqzEbeTbJVM_WmQrJtBEAAaCD7G50AAMBAAMCAAN4AAMJ3QEAAR4E","file_unique_id":"AQADoIPsbnQAAwndAQAB","file_size":22167,"width":640,"height":360}]},"reply_markup":{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Play Lucky Spin","callback_game":{}}]]}}}
```

The game was successfully sent to my telegram account, but when I click the Play button, there's no callback data that I can use to pass into my game URL, here is  the output of getupdates method :

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":677451492,
"callback_query":{"id":"279653697655933338","from":{"id":65111950,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Fredy Kardian","last_name":"Udo","username":"fredykardian","language_code":"en"},"message":{"message_id":316,"from":{"id":1657959350,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"fred Admin Bot","username":"fredAdminBot"},"chat":{"id":[chat id],"first_name":"Fredy Kardian","last_name":"Udo","username":"fredykardian","type":"private"},"date":1612566258,"game":{"title":"Lucky Spin","description":"Lucky Spin","photo":[{"file_id":"AgACAgUAAxUAAWAdzvLbYgEGIlW5Ox2vkzdrY_vfAAIgqzEbeTbJVM_WmQrJtBEAAaCD7G50AAMBAAMCAANtAAMI3QEAAR4E","file_unique_id":"AQADoIPsbnQAAwjdAQAB","file_size":10256,"width":320,"height":180},{"file_id":"AgACAgUAAxUAAWAdzvLbYgEGIlW5Ox2vkzdrY_vfAAIgqzEbeTbJVM_WmQrJtBEAAaCD7G50AAMBAAMCAAN4AAMJ3QEAAR4E","file_unique_id":"AQADoIPsbnQAAwndAQAB","file_size":22167,"width":640,"height":360}]},"reply_markup":{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Play Lucky Spin","callback_game":{}}]]}},"chat_instance":"9169438509256759524","game_short_name":"luckySpin"}}]}
```

How can I pass an ID ? Please help